# Different Qt::CheckStateRole for different views?

Tags: qt, qt4

Currently I have a simple setup where I maintain a list of bools corresponding to each item in my ListModel:

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/ModelView/StringListModelCheckable

However, now what I want to do is have two such lists bools, say IsHot and IsLarge. Then I want to have a ListView that displays each string with a checkbox for one of the bools (the "Hot" view), and a separate ListView that displays each string with a checkbox for the other bool (the "Large" bool). Any hints on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your model a table, return the data in two different columns, the cells in these columns will be checkable.

On your list views, call [`QListView::setModelColumn`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlistview.html#modelColumn-prop) to set the column the list view displays.

If you want to synchronise scrolling between the lists, you would then be better using a QTableView, so that rows would match up.

---

Edit to add more detail on returning text and check state.

To return a text and the state of a checkbox from the model you return different data for different *roles* from the [data] function on your model.

From the [manual for `Qt::ItemDataRole`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum):

> `Qt::DisplayRole` The key data to be rendered in the form of text. (`QString`)
>   `Qt::CheckStateRole` This role is used to obtain the checked state of an item. (`Qt::CheckState`)

Both columns in your model would return the same data (the name) for `DisplayRole` but different data for `CheckStateRole`

Comment: That almost sounds good... the problem I want the text in the ListView to display the Name column, but the checkbox be linked to the IsHot column. If the text displayed came from the same column as the checkable item, the ListView would just display "true" or "false" with a checkbox next to it, which isn't helpful. See what I mean?

Comment: Your model can return whatever text it likes along with a checkbox, see edited answer.